# Is it possible to retrieve data from an object which has lookup relationship with other object and display in report

Tags: reporting, opportunity, customization, joined-reports

I have 3 objects opp1,mile2,cust3.

- mile2 and cust3 are related list in opp1
- mile2 has opp1 as lookup field
- cust3 has opp1 as master detail

I have to create a report which have some fields in mile2 and some fields in cust3  with same opp1.

I have tried creating joined report but only opp1 with cust3 data is getting displayed where opp1 with mile2 is empty.
What is the reason for that, Can someone help me with detailed solution?

If some could explain with screen shot after trying this scenario. It would be great.

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: How did you create the report? with or without "Report Types"?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a Report Type (Setup-->Build-->Create-->Report Types)

2) Select your Primary Object as **opp1** and Choose "Store in Category" as "Other Reports" and click on Next.

3) For Choosing related object, "Click to relate another object" and choose **mile2**.

4) Again click on "Click to relate another Object" and Choose **cust3**.

5) Save your Report Type and Create "New Report" on Reports Object. After that choose your created Report Type in the list and Click on "Create"

There you can find every field of 3 Objects to create a report

Hope this helps.....

Comment: it will be Like A related to B, and B related to C. What he wants is A related to B and C. I find report type wont be useful here.

Comment: did you try to create the report type? Is that list not showing the Object that you want?

Answer (score 0):

Joined reports will be the solution.

1. Reports Tab> New Report> Select **mile2** as the report type.
2. Select Joined Report from the format dropdown
3. Click '**Add Report type**'
4. Select and add '**cust3**' report type
5. 2 Report blocks will get created side by side(One for each Report Type)
6. Group the two blocks by a common field(Common Fields will be available in the left..Drag and drop it in the group by area..)

This will solve the issue..

Comment: My User want a single report, Like for Object Opp1 , List of mile2 object fields like mile2 name , deadline date, kickoff data etc and custom object cust3 name, state city etc . as Mile2 and cust3 are related list under object opp1. mile2 has lookup relationship with opp1 and cust3 has master detail relationship with opp1 . Please help with solution .

Comment: @sai - A Joint report just creates a single report by combining two report types. Your requirement is a perfect example for a Joint Report. Joint reports are available in enterprise and unlimited editions only. 
Follow the steps above and let know of any deviations..

Comment: We are using professional edition so there should some way to professional edition right. Please let me know